# Where are the Visual Studio sdk samples?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

II want to download this samples http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1370z17c(v=vs.90).aspx but I instal Visual Studio 2012 and I do not find the folder \Program Files\Program Files\Visual Studio 9.0\Samples\Samples\

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Visual Studio 2012 samples have been relocated.  You can find them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se881ay9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and in the MSDN Code Gallery.

Comment: I could download all the standard examples in Visual Studio 2010.How do it in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I have this problem too, where is this folder relocated?